# How to force System.Text.Json serializer throw exception when property is missing?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, exception, system.text.json

Json.NET behaviour could be defined by attributes: either use default or just throw an exception if json payload does not contain required property.

Yet `System.Text.Json` serializer silently does nothing.
Having class:

```
public sealed class Foo
{
    [Required]
    public int Prop {get;set;} = 10;
}
```

and deserializing empty object:

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>("{}");
```

I simply get an instance of `Foo` with `Prop=10`.
I could not find any setting in [`JsonSerializerOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=netcore-3.1) to force it throw an exception. Is it possible?

Comment: According to [required properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#required-properties) you should create custom converter

Comment: System.Text.Json isn't a full replacement for Json.NET. It's built for speed with minimal allocations in mind, not feature completeness. If you want validations you can 1) use Json.NET 2) validate the objects *after* serialisation with the [Validator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator?view=netcore-3.1) class  or 3) create a custom converter

Comment: Check [Manual Validation with Data Annotations](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx) for the 2nd option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System.Text.Json doesn't throw an exception if no value is received for one of the properties of the target type. You need to implement a custom converter.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#required-properties

Answer (score 5):

The `[JsonRequired]` attribute from `System.Text.Json` works as requested, but it is available starting with .NET 7. See [Required properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/required-properties) documentation.

In addition, in .NET 8 you can also force the JSON string to properly map to POCO/model properties using `JsonUnmappedMemberHandling.Disallow` option. See [Handle missing members during deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/missing-members) documentation.

Comment: Hm, it would be much better if missing property handling was a setting in JsonSerializerOptions as well, because on may need to allow/disallow missing properties based on the use case rather than on the model.

Answer (score 4):

System.Text.Json isn't a full replacement for Json.NET. It's built for speed with minimal allocations in mind, not feature completeness. If you want validations you can

1. Use Json.NET
2. Validate the objects after serialisation with the [Validator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator?view=netcore-3.1) class
3. Create a custom converter

TheGeneral showed how to do #3. A custom validator would have to handle *all* validations explicitly and return some meaningful exception though. Throwing an `ArgumentNullException` is enough if there's only a single property to check. Validating multiple properties would require something more complex like a [ValidationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationexception?view=netcore-3.1) to include the validation results.

K. Scott Allen's article [Manual Validation with Data Annotations](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx) shows how to do #2.

One option is to use the [Validator.ValidateObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.validateobject?view=netcore-3.1#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_Validator_ValidateObject_System_Object_System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationContext_) to validate an object and get a `ValidationException` with all the failing validations :

```
try
{
    var validationCtx=new ValidationContexgt(myFoo);
    Validator.ValidateObject(myFoo,validationCtx);
}
catch(ValidatinException ex)
{
    //Do something with the results.
}
```

This is OK if invalid objects are rare, as throwing exceptions is expensive. Perhaps a better option is to use [Validator.TryValidateObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateobject?view=netcore-3.1#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_Validator_TryValidateObject_System_Object_System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationContext_System_Collections_Generic_ICollection_System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationResult__) :

```
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
var validationCtx=new ValidationContexgt(myFoo);
if(Validator.TryValidateObject(myFoo,validationCtx,results))
{
    //Use the object
}
else
{
    //Do something with the failed results
}
```

Comment: The problem with validation is that default instance may be absolutely valid, but at the time of validating we won't knkow whether payload was correct.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do SetMissingMemberHandling and it will handle every thing for you but you need to install [DevBetter.JsonExtensions](https://github.com/DevBetterCom/DevBetter.JsonExtensions)
MissingMemberHandling.Ignore and MissingMemberHandling.Error

```cs
var deserializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions()
    .SetMissingMemberHandling(MissingMemberHandling.Ignore);

var weatherForecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>(jsonString, deserializeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in an implementation of `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver`, which marks every property as required.

```
using System.Text.Json;

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions {
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver {
        Modifiers = {
            typeInfo => {
                foreach (JsonPropertyInfo property in typeInfo.Properties) {
                    property.IsRequired = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(content, options);
```