# How to manually deserialize JSON and validate model like Web API does it automatically?

Tags: json, validation, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi, model-validation

When posting JSON to Web API, not only does it get deserialized automatically, one can also use model validation like

```
// ItemPostRequest
class ItemPostRequest {
    [Required] // this will automatically be validated and errors created if it is missing
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

However in my case, I only have a string containing JSON. I can deserialize it using  `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ItemPostRequest>(myJsonString);` but that's missing the validation.

How to use the validation / how to manually deserialize and validate JSON like Web API does it internally?

In my case the JSON string is part of form-data with keys like `file` and `json`, but the form-data formatter only cares about splitting the form-data into key-value pairs, it doesn't care about deserializing the json and the model validation for it. So I have to do this manually - but how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force System.Text.Json serializer throw exception when property is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62570159/how-to-force-system-text-json-serializer-throw-exception-when-property-is-missin)

Answer (score 1):

Deserialize the JSON in a model binder, like written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49471892
Then the validation will be done automatically :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like below.  I have not tested it, but you should be able to use TryValidateModel() to manually validate your ItemPostRequest based on your class annotations (e.g. [Required]).

```
// Deserialize
var itemPostRequest = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ItemPostRequest>(myJsonString);
// Reset just in case
ModelState.Clear();
// Manually validate the model using the annotations on the model class
TryValidateModel(itemPostRequest);

// If it fails, return error
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   return BadRequest(ModelState);
}

// Otherwise we're good, keep going...
```

Comment: Thank you, that indeed likely works, but there's much code in the action method when doing it that way. I ended up using a model binder (see my own answer).